# JPA - Mapping OneToMany association between the same table using an intermediate table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm creating an application where one large aspect is the ability for users to share content with friends. I'm trying to represent this in the object model and I'm having trouble getting the association to work properly. I'm using a mapping table that records the friender and the friendee, both of which are represented by the primary key (id) of the user. A user can have many friends, and also be referenced by other users. This is what the schema looks like:

```
Users:
int user_id (PK)
varchar(32) email
varchar(64) password

Users_Map:
int users_map_id (PK)
int friendee_id (FK references users(user_id))
int friender_id (FK references users(user_id))
```

And this is how I have the User entity set up:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "users_map",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "friender_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "friendee_id") })
    private List<User> friends;
}
```

I run into the following error when deploying the application:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering
>   com.x.webapp.data.entity.User from
>   com.x.webapp.data.entity.User has the wrong number of
>   column. should be 2

I've tried quite a few other configurations, including adding a "referencedColumnName" attribute to each @JoinColumn, but they have also yielded errors. I'm also not entirely sure whether the schema I currently have is the best way to go about mapping users together.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Just a note: what you describe is a ManyToMany, not a OneToMany.

Comment: where is the definition of "friends_map" table? if you mean "users_map" then why is there a column "users_map_id" that is not part of the relation?

Comment: Oops, what was a typo - it's users_map. What do you mean by "not part of the relation"? It has no meaning to the mapping between users - should it be replaced/removed? I also get the same error when changing the relation to ManyToMany.

Comment: A 1-N/M-N join table with Set or List (without ordering) will have 2 columns, the FKs, and they would form the PK. Hence why there is no annotation to define some artificial "id" for the join table in JPA

Comment: I dropped the users_friend_id and made a composite primary key consisting of friender_id and friendee_id, and the same error still occurs. Is this what you were suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the extension of AbstractPersistable fixed the problem - that contained an @Id reference and clashed with the @Id reference I put inside of User.